# Generating an always balanced binary seach tree only true insertion

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

So i was thinking of a problem i find very interesting and i would like to share the concept of this, the problem starts of with an hypotetical data structure you define (it can be a list, array, tree, binary search tree, red black tree, Btree, etc.), the goal of this is obviously to optimize insertion, search, delete and update (but you can consider this as a search with replacement), the time complexity has to be has low as possible for every single type of operation (possibly O(1) or O(log(n) try to not use a solution of O(n)) the second part of the problem is that this structure during a normal day of work receives new elements with a key of increasing value starting from 1 to N where N can be Long.MAX_LONG, obviously when a new key is given it has to be inserted immediately so it will go as follows:

> [1,2,3,4,...,N]

I think i am close to the solution of this problem but i am missing a little bit more of optimization, i was thinking of using either a Tree or a Hashtable but in the case of Hashtable there is a problem when N becomes very high  it's needed to rehash the entire structure or the complexity would become O(n), this however is not a problem with a Tree but i think it may become a sequence of elements (keep in mind that we have to put every new element when it comes) like this:

[image]

And in this case you can clearly see that this Tree is not just a Tree it's a List, using a BST would give the same result.
I think the correct structure to use is the BST (or something like it for example Red Black Tree) and find a way to always have it balanced, but i am missing something.

Comment: `N can be Long.MAX_LONG` In java that means up 2^63 elements. In what kind of storage would you keep this data-structure? Definitly not in RAM. If storage is no problem, you could go with a 128bit hash-key to reduce the collisions in your Hashtable.

Comment: *"something like it for example Red Black Tree, and find a way to always have it balanced, but i am missing something"*: with red-black tree you don't have to find a way to keep it balanced, because that is a *feature* that comes with it. See [self-balanced binary tree implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree#Implementations) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @MrSmith42 i am sorry it was meant to be just an example for a high number, i didn't know that, as i have said it's a problem i invented i take full responability for my inaccuracy and i am thankful to the people who will correct me.

Comment: @trincot i imagined that but don't understand how the balancing method of the red-black tree works, does it balance the entire tree based on every insertion?

Comment: No, a self-balancing tree will perform a "local" rebalancing so that roughly the two subtrees of a node never have a height difference of more than 1. But this does not mean that the tree as a whole is *perfectly* balanced. It is just balanced enough to ensure logn operations. If the tree were to balance the tree perfectly (i.e. all leaves at the deepest or one-but-least level), that rebalancing operation could itself kill the time complexity. So there is a middle ground that all self-balancing trees find.

Comment: You could look into B trees: they combine the power of arrays with trees. They are self-balancing.

Comment: @trincot thanks to what you have just said i found the solution to my problem, what i was really searching (and didn't know of) is the meaning of AVL tree, which as you suggested locally swaps subtrees granting the O(log(n)) operations.

Answer (score 0):

If the "key" is an integer and the key are generated by incrementing a counter starting from 1, then the obvious data structure for representing the key -> value mapping is a `ValueType[]`.  Yes, an array.

There are two problems with this:

1. Arrays do not "grow" in Java.

   Solutions:

   1. Preallocate the array to be big enough to start with.
   2. Use an `ArrayList` instead of a array.
   3. "Borrow" the algorithm that `ArrayList` uses to grow a list and use it with a bare array.
2. Arrays cannot have more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements.  (And `ArrayList` has the same problem.

   Solution: use an array of arrays, and do some arithmetic to convert the `long` keys into a pair of `int`s for indexing the arrays.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but the complexity of the operations would be to high, atleast i think.

Comment: Nope.  `O(1)` ... if I understand what you want the data structure to do.  (Your description is not at all clear.)  Even "growing" the data structure is `O(1)` amortized if you grow in powers of 2.  (Contrast with trees which will be `O(logN)` ...)

Comment: Yes that is very true, but searching and deleting would be O(n) am i right?

Comment: Nope.  Searching by key is just indexing.  That's `O(1)`.  Deletion by key is just assignment of a `null` in the relevant array or list cell: `O(1)`.